# How to use import tools for K2 in Joomla to import CSV?

Tags: mysql, csv, joomla3.0

I'm upgrading my joomla site from v1.5 to latest joomla version. So i need to import the required data from old database to new one. For importing i'm using K2 import/export tools.

I have read the documentation here [Instructions for K2 Import Component](http://www.individual-it.net/en/Instructions-for-K2-Import-Component.html).
But couldn't understand the flow.

Can any body show me the correct way to import the data from old database to new one ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1.5 to 3.* you might find spupgrade easier to use.  k2 is one of the supported extensions:

http://cyend.com/extensions/extensions/components/5-upgrade-joomla-from-15-to-16